# How do environmental conditions differ between nitrogen fixing bacteria and denitrification bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I am currently experimenting with aquaponics and need to better understand nitrifying and denitrifying bacteria.

From my research it seems that both varieties are anaerobic. From an engineering perspective, how would I control the environment such that nitrifying bacteria would dominate a water medium or vice versa? I'm thinking some combination of the following should provide some level of control; pH, temperature, surface area, tds, nitrogen partial pressure, concentrations of fixed nitrogen and types, etc.